# What's the bleeding-edge model for how Population III stars are born and evolve?

Tags: star, stellar-evolution

I'm trying to do a brief literature review to find out what the best current models for population III stellar evolution are. I was hoping that someone with more expertise in the area could perhaps summarise or point me in the right direction.

[This post](https://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/26271/how-can-a-population-iii-star-be-so-massive) on physics.SE is a great intro, but it's now over 4 years old.

Recent observations (see [here](http://arxiv.org/pdf/1504.01734.pdf) and [here](http://www.nytimes.com/2015/06/18/science/space/astronomers-report-finding-earliest-stars-that-enriched-cosmos.html?_r=0)) suggest hints of these kinds of stars at relatively low redshift (z ~ 6) - does this provide significant tension on current models? Have there been other observational hints?

Comment: Try these searches: http://physics.stackexchange.com/search?q=+III+stars and  http://astronomy.stackexchange.com/search?q=+III+stars

Comment: @Aabaakawad I'm looking for a more comprehensive review, rather than the few specific questions found on SE

Comment: From 2014 till now, arXiv returns [50 hits on "population III"](http://arxiv.org/find/astro-ph/1/ti:+AND+population+iii/0/1/0/2014,2015,2016/0/1?per_page=100). Most seem to be rather specific, but e.g. the review by [Toma et al. (2016)](http://arxiv.org/abs/1603.04640) might be of interest.

Answer (score 2):

This is a more recent review http://arxiv.org/abs/1209.4688 from someone hoping to understand population III by observing their supernovae

Since CR7 was discovered, there's been a bunch of papers on whether it could be pop III - http://arxiv.org/abs/1506.07173 for example. Try searching for "CR7 population III".

Comment: While the links are useful, it is always a good idea to add some of the key information from them in the answer.

Comment: I wrote about the Sobral CR7 paper [here](https://astrobites.org/2015/12/25/observational-evidence-for-the-first-generation-of-stars/), the jury is still out on whether it's actually made up of PopIII, and it's relatively late evolution suggests it could have formed very differently to the majority of the PopIII stars